# Dynamic User Control saving ViewState

Tags: c#, user-controls, viewstate, webforms

I am using a DropDownList to let a user select a form template.  The user then posts back to the server and the user controls from the template are dynamically rendered to the page.  Once the user fills in the form and clicks save, the ViewState for the user controls are lost and values are empty.

### Page Controls

```
<air:CreateEditForm ID="CreateEditForm" runat="server" />

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phDynamicControls" runat="server" />

<p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCreate" runat="server" Text="Create" OnClick="btnCreate_Click" CssClass="action-button" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CssClass="action-button" Visible="false" />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="linkCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" NavigateUrl="Index.aspx" CssClass="action-button" />
</p>
```

### Page Code

```
protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CreateDynamicSteps();
}

private void CreateDynamicSteps()
{
  foreach (WorkflowTemplate workflowTemplate in template.WorkflowTemplates)
  {
    foreach (WorkflowTemplateStep workflowStep in workflowTemplate.WorkflowTemplateSteps)
    {
        if (workflowStep.SubSteps.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (WorkflowTemplateStep workflowSubStep in workflowStep.SubSteps)
            {
                if (workflowSubStep.WhoIsDynamic)
                {
                    dynamicSteps.Add(workflowSubStep);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (workflowStep.WhoIsDynamic)
        {
            dynamicSteps.Add(workflowStep);
        }
    }
  }

  // removed for brevity

  foreach (WorkflowTemplateStep dynamicStep in dynamicSteps)
  {
    PersonSelectorDialog personSelector = (PersonSelectorDialog)LoadControl("~/Pages/UserControls/PersonSelectorDialog.ascx");
    personSelector.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
    personSelector.LabelID = "lbl" + dynamicStep.ID;
    personSelector.Label = dynamicStep.Name + " Selector";
    DynamicPersonSelectorDialogs.Add(personSelector);
  }

  // removed for brevity
}

private void LoadControls()
{
  foreach (PersonSelectorDialog personSelector in DynamicPersonSelectorDialogs)
  {
    Label title = new Label();
    title.ID = personSelector.LabelID;
    title.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
    title.Text = personSelector.Label;
    phDynamicControls.Controls.Add(title);

    phDynamicControls.Controls.Add(personSelector);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the user selects the form template from the dropdown and the postback is triggered, that value needs to be retained somewhere because when you perform the second postback you need to load the usercontrol again from the first postback.

Comment: This is intuitive.  The question is how should the values in the User Control be stored in order to grab the value on the Postback.